# Using the Marketing Cloud REST API, can a value in a row in a data extension be changed if the column is part of the primary key?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketingcloudapi

I am considering using this endpoint:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/putDataExtensionRowByKey.html

to insert and update (UPSERT) values.

Is it possible to use this endpoint to change the value of a column in an existing row if the column is part of the data extension's primary key?

Say, for example, that I have a Data Extension with these columns:

- PrimaryKeyColumn
- NonPrimaryKeyColumn

Where PrimaryKeyColumn is a primary key and NonPrimaryKeyColumn is not.

If I insert a row with with PrimaryKeyColumn = "foo", can I then subsequently update that row to change PrimaryKeyColumn to "bar"?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with any API or anything else. It is due to the basic concept of data extension in SFMC. A primary key is used to identify a row uniquely in the data extension. If you change a value for the Primary key column it will simply insert a new record. The best way for you to achieve this is to completely remove the old rows and then insert new rows with the new primary key.

Comment: There are numerous database systems that allow changing the a value in a column that is part of a primary key.  MySQL is just one example.

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update your answer.  I hope my feedback has been more useful than confrontational!  My experiments still do not support your conclusion.  I have been able to change the value of columns in SF MC DEs that are part of the DE's primary key.  See my answer for a more detailed example of what I mean.

Answer (score -4):

This IS possible.

For example, you can create a row like so:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
PUT /hub/v1/dataevents/key:KEY/rows/Email:before@example.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "keys": {
            "Email":"before@example.com"
             },
    "values":{
            "LastLogin":"2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
            "IsActive":true,
            "FirstName":"John",
            "FollowerCount":2,
            "LastName":"Smith"
             }
}
```

and then change the Email value in the row like so:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
PUT /hub/v1/dataevents/key:KEY/rows/Email:before@example.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "keys": {
            "Email":"after@example.com"
             },
    "values":{
            "LastLogin":"2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
            "IsActive":true,
            "FirstName":"John",
            "FollowerCount":2,
            "LastName":"Smith"
             }
}
```

After the second PUT, there will be only one row and it will have Email of "after@example.com".

Comment: Some additional detail would likely help other people with the same or similar issues, please [edit] your answer to add more details.

Comment: Are you sure this is the case, and you don’t just add another row with a PK value of “bar”?

Comment: yes, please add details. It _shouldn't_ work, but tbh I wouldn't even be surprised if SFMC somehow allowed that to happen. Then it would be quite interesting how it handles newly introduced PK violations - say, if you managed to update, but you updated it to a PK value already present on some other record. Will you then have two records with the same PK? Will THAT break? Again - it shouldn't work, and if it does, I would exercise extreme caution.

Comment: Updated with much more detail.

Comment: Just did same test as you. When pushing similar payload to your last example {"keys": {"id":"4"},"values":{"email":"lukas@example.com","name":"Lukas"}} PUT to /hub/v1/dataevents/KEY/rows/id:5, I receive a response containing the old key value: {"keys": {"id": "5"},"values": {"email": "lukas@example.com","name": "Lukas"}}, which is confirmed by checking the DE in UI

Comment: @LukasLunow Hrm.  Strange.  Perhaps there is some difference in the underlying configuration of the DE that could explain why we are seeing different results?  I would be game to collab on this in realtime using a dev org or similar to get to the bottom of the myster.